# jQuery remove() failing on table row with tablesorter plugin

Tags: jquery

I have a delete button for each row in a table. After an ajax call completes successfully, the `tr` is supposed to be removed from the DOM.

Before the `$.ajax` section, I define the variable `var $row = $(this).closest('tr')` and inside of the ajax I confirm that I have the right row.

inside of the `$.ajax`, I have this:

```
success: function(response) {
  if(response.success == 1) {
    alert('success');
    if(typeof $row == 'undefined' ) {
      alert('undefined!'); // this alert does not come up
    } else {
      alert('the $row var is defined'); // this alert DOES come up
      $row.html('hahaha'); // this works, the contents of the row are replaced
      $row.remove(); // this doesn't work. The row is still there, with 'hahaha'
    }
  } else {
    alert('failed');
  }
}
```

How can this be? Am I not allowed to remove a row inside of a script that is called based on it?

Here is full code. I have it hide the row immediately, and then remove if ajax is successful, show it again if it fails. `remove()` doesn't work, whether or not I first `hide()` it.

```
$(document).on("click",".allowed_val_delete",function() { // 20150328
    var $this_row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var allowed_val_id = $this_row.attr("id").split('_')[1];
    var data = new Object();
    //alert('Delete allowed value with id "' + allowed_val_id + '"');
    data.action = 'DELETE';
    data.id = parseInt(allowed_val_id,10);
    $this_row.hide(); // hide row immediately. Show it again if ajax fails.

    $.ajax({
        data: data,
        //type: "POST",
        type: "POST", // 20150502 experimenting with other HTTP methods. (method is alias for type but requies jquery 1.9+)
        url: "controllers/core_fields/ajax/allowed_values.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            if(response.success == 1) {
                //alert('Removing row');
                if(typeof $this_row == 'undefined') {
                    alert('$this_row with val_id = ' + allowed_val_id + ' is undefined');
                } else {
                    //alert('$this_row with val_id = ' + allowed_val_id + ' is defined');
                    $this_row.remove(); // doesn't work                 
                }
                /*var index = allowed_value_ids.indexOf(allowed_val_id);
                allowed_value_ids.splice(index,1); // remove from the list of ids*/
                $("#maintable").tablesorter().trigger("update"); // updates sorting
                $("#maintable").tablesorter().trigger("appendCache"); // updates sorting
            } else {
                alert('Failed to remove');
                $this_row.show();
            }
            //alert('action: ' + response.action + '; id: ' + response.id);
            //alert(response);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: does it hide it when you try `$row.hide();`

Comment: @erkaner yes it does. And maybe I would use that, but why wouldn't `remove()` work?

Comment: @ShaunakD there it is. Work your magic, sir.

Comment: I think these lines `$("#maintable").tablesorter().trigger("update");           $("#maintable").tablesorter().trigger("appendCache")` are conflicting with the .remove() code in else{}… not sure what those are for.

Comment: Should be using `tablesorter` API to remove the row in the first place

Comment: does $($this_row).remove() work?

Comment: @ShaunakD removing those lines does make it work, but I don't understand why. I am calling `$this_row.remove` before those lines. Are they adding the row back in?

Comment: @charlietfl I'm looking for the relevant API method. I found `addRows` and a reference to deleting here: http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-add-rows.html

Comment: The plugin stores data in cache which allows it t render far faster than looping through the DOM

Comment: @Eric no. It did something strange and removed a different row. I'm not sure why I would wrap a jQuery object inside of another jQuery call. Why?

Comment: @ButtleButkus, I've faced the issue where it would lose the reference to the original object in callbacks and I had to rewrap it

Comment: @Eric I believe I proved that the original reference still existed by trying `$this_row.html('hahaha')`, which worked as expected. It seems it is a conflict with the tablesorter plugin, as Shaunak D and charlietfl suggest.

Comment: @ButtleButkus, also reference obj might be overwritten because the ajax call is asynchronous and by the time it returns, the reference has changed

Comment: `remove()` is likely working and because you aren't removing from plugin internal cache it gets redrawn

Comment: @Eric, see my last comment. I don't think you are correct. It seems that `remove()` is working, but my subsequent calls to the tablesorter plugin put the row back in. I was using tablesorter update/appendCache before when I updated cell values and it worked as I expected. But apparently those calls are not needed when deleting rows.

Comment: @charlietfl it seems like you are right. I am surprised, because update/appendCache work for updated cell values. I thought they would be needed for removing rows but perhaps they are not.

Comment: @ButtleButkus, hope you figure it out